# Blender cycles and blender internal look the same and my materials are too shiny even on diffuse

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Blender cycles and blender internal look the same and my materials are too shiny even on diffuse. I want my cycles object to turn whiter instead of being grey like the blender internal. Here is a screenshot of how they look; First is the cycles object that looks the same as the blender internal instead of turning whiter. Second is the material on diffuse.
[image: Here is the cycles object that looks the same as the blender internal instead of turning whiter]
[image: This is the material on diffuse]

Answer (score 6):

In your screenshots only the OpenGL viewport "preview" shading is being used; to see what your materials actually look like when rendered with BI or cycles, switch from *Solid* shading to *Rendered* in *3D view > Header* (or press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)

[image]

You can adjust the way a cycles material is rendered in solid view via the options in *Materials > Settings*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man but i was talking about why my cycles view port object looks grey instead of white

Comment: @barise I would guess it's because *Use Nodes* is disabled

Comment: i attempted that it didn't seem to work, thanks for your help man